# PGF/TikZ arrow line width not consistent with line width

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a document I created several months back, and maybe with a new version of PGF/TikZ it is not working as previously (currently using Arch Linux, TexLive 2011, pgf version 2.10). The fast question is that I have a picture like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw [line width=4pt,->,line join=round,line cap=round,red!50] (tl2) -- (tl1);
```

where `tl2` and `tl1` are previously defined nodes. Line is displayed right, with a width of 4pt, but the cap is displayed as if the line had a smaller width, obtaining the following:

[image: arrow tip with inconsistent width]

The question is, how can I get the tip of the same width as the line?

This may be related with this other question regarding line width in layers, but I'm not sure: [Bug in TikZ? Line width on layers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33601/bug-in-tikz-line-width-on-layers)

**EDIT**:

I include minimal compilable code to show the behavior:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=3.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

I have ...

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\coordinate[xshift=-1.8cm] (tl1) at ([yshift=-2cm]current page.north east);
\coordinate[xshift=-1.8cm,yshift=2cm] (tl2) at (current page.south east);
\draw [line cap=round,line width=4pt,->,red!50] (tl2)  -- (tl1);
\node [above,right=5pt,scale=.7,color=black!50] at (tl1) {timeline};
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage

\end{document}
```

I use remember picture because I reuse the `tl1` and `tl2` nodes defined here.

**SOLUTION**:

Well, I found `pdflatex` fails with that rendering, but the combination, for example, of `latex` + `dvipdf` works as expected. I checked this with Ubuntu 11.10 and Arch Linux, both running TexLive 2011, so the problem may reside in the TL2011's `pdflatex`.

Comment: I get an arrow tip with the same width. It would be good if you would provide a compilable minimal example which shows the inconsistency.

Comment: OK, I'll prepare it ASAP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An minimal example, which shows a correct arrow tip:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\putnode}[2][]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\node (#2) {#1};}}
\begin{document}
\putnode{tl1}

\vspace{2cm}
\putnode{tl2}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw [line width=4pt,->,line join=round,line cap=round,red!50] (tl2) -- (tl1);
  \node [right of=tl1, color=gray] {\Large\textsf{timeline}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}​
```

Compiled also with TeX Live 2011 and pgf 2.10:

[image: arrow with tip]

Comment: Yes, this is the minimal example. I found the error. My pdflatex is not working properly. I don't know exactly why. I tried `latex`, then `dvipdf` and the final document shows the expected result. I'll try reinstall my latex package.

Comment: Amazing, it is consistently failing in pdflatex in Ubuntu 11.10 *and* Arch Linux (both with TexLive 2011). This has to be a problem in pdflatex from that distro. I'll stick to latex+dvipdf in the meantime... Thanks for the example.