# Setting line width when using set layers in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I've been using pgfplots for some plots.  I prefer using relatively thick lines in my plots which I feel are better suited to the font I'm using in my figures, accomplished with something like `line width=1pt` in the options to `\begin{axis}`.  However, I'm now in the process of adding a second y-axis to a plot.  The pgfplots manual says that I should use `set layers`.  However, when I add `set layers`, I lose the effect of changing the line width.  Any ideas for how I can get the `line width` parameter to stick to the axis lines, ticks, plot line, and so on?

While hunting around, I stumbled upon [Bug in TikZ? Line width on layers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33601/bug-in-tikz-line-width-on-layers) which seems related, but since I'm not really a TikZ or pgfplots expert, I'm not sure how to apply the conclusion in that Q&A.

Here's a simple example using a single axis and plot, which shows the problem I'd like to overcome:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{set layers} % commenting this line makes line width work

\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,
    xmax=4,
    line width=1pt,
    every tick/.style={black}
]

\addplot {x^2};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

With `set layers` active (undesirable behaviour):

[image: Using <code>set layers</code>]

After commenting `set layers` (what I want to see, but while using `set layers`):

[image: After commenting <code>set layers</code>]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see if this helps:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{set layers=axis on top,
             axis line style={line width=1pt},
             every axis plot post/.append style={line width=1pt}
             }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0, xmax=4,
            ]
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that does help, thank you, I probably wouldn't have figured `every axis plot post` on my own.  I also added tick style={black,line width=1pt} to the `\pgfplotsset` command, to get the ticks to match the example.  I wonder why the line widths all have to be set separately, though...

Comment: @Tyler, i focused only on width of lines (your question is about them).   `pgfplotset ` you can move to preamble and collect in it all common presets.  widths of lines is deliberately determined separately. only on this way you can control them separately.