# Restore TikZ settings after {pgfonlayer}

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is kind of a follow up question of [Bug in TikZ? Line width on layers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33601/4918).

---

When using a `{pgfonlayer}` two problem occure: a) inside of the background scope settings from e.g. `every picture` are missing. b) for drawing commands *after* closing `{pgfonlayer}` the settings that where active *before* `{pgfonlayer}` are lost. While a) seems to be “by design”, I’m not sure about b).

The code below produces this image:
[image: result]
1) is made with `on baclground layer` and works as documented.
2) is wrong
3) is the fixed version of 2)
4) and 5) are wrong
6) is again the fixed version.

As you can see it requires two additional `{scope}`s to get the desired result. While [Christian suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33654/4918) only one as solution in the above mentioned question. This doesn’t seem to work (anymore?).

So basically the question is which of these might be a bug and is worth reporting?

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{%
   backgrounds,%
}

\tikzset{
   medium/.style={line width=2.5pt},
   thin/.style={line width=0.5pt},
   every picture/.append style={medium},
   every scope/.style={medium},
   every on background layer/.style={every picture},
}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\begin{document}
1 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
   \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \draw [red] (0,1) -- (1,0);
   \end{scope}
   \draw (0,0) -- (1,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
2 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      \draw [red] (0,1) -- (1,0);
   \end{pgfonlayer}
   \draw (0,0) -- (1,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
3 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
   \begin{scope}
      \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
         \begin{scope}
            \draw [red] (0,1) -- (1,0);
         \end{scope}
      \end{pgfonlayer}
   \end{scope}
   \draw (0,0) -- (1,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
4 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
      \draw [red] (0,1) -- (1,0);
   \end{pgfonlayer}
   \draw (0,0) -- (1,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
5 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
      \begin{scope}
         \draw [red] (0,1) -- (1,0);
      \end{scope}
   \end{pgfonlayer}
   \draw (0,0) -- (1,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
6 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
   \begin{scope}
      \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
         \begin{scope}
            \draw [red] (0,1) -- (1,0);
         \end{scope}
      \end{pgfonlayer}
   \end{scope}
   \draw (0,0) -- (1,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the `on background layer` of `tikzlibrarybackgrounds.code.tex`, you could build your own style that does not reset the `\tikz@options`, such that after the scope you'll be fine. This still requires you to smuggle `medium` into the scope with `every scope/.style={medium}`. But you could drop `every on background layer/.style={every picture},`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{%
   backgrounds,%
}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
on layer/.style={
    execute at begin scope={%
      \pgfonlayer{#1}%
      \tikz@options
      },
    execute at end scope={\endpgfonlayer}
  }
}%
\makeatother

\tikzset{
   medium/.style={line width=2.5pt},
   thin/.style={line width=0.5pt},
   every picture/.append style={medium},
   every scope/.append style={medium},
%    every on background layer/.style={every picture},
}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\begin{document}
1 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
   \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \draw [red] (0,1) -- (1,0);
   \end{scope}
   \draw (0,0) -- (1,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
2 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
   \begin{scope}[on layer=background]
      \draw [red] (0,1) -- (1,0);
   \end{scope}
   \draw (0,0) -- (1,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Do you think I should report the behaviour as a bug?

Comment: @Tobi I don't know. I guess, if at all I would call it a feature request. (I personally would be very interested in something that would allow one to carry the `\tikz@options` somewhere and to switch them off locally, which would mitigate the problems associated with nesting Ti*k*Z pictures.)

Comment: @marmot In 3.1.3 I introduced [`\pgfutil@pushmacro` and `\pgfutil@popmacro`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/commit/e846933f1497e23f0dee0554d2af8ba0d23aff34) which allows you to carry definitions over an `\egroup`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Good to know, thanks! I wonder if you want to add an answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470961/121799). I am also wondering how this differs from `\pgfmathsmuggle` that has been added in 3.1.1. Could you perhaps add this explanation, too?